# SF book series with main character that had a golden suit which was paired with a golden spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books

It has been decades, but some details I remember. Humanity had become immortal either through technology or cloning. Set in our solar system. There was a super soldier who was actually the last soldier. The Golden suit and ship were paired and used to harness our suns power. Maybe?

Comment: Maybe "The Golden Transcendence" by John C. Wright?

Comment: Yes! You nailed it, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help @Jack. Can you click the green tick to accept my answer? Then everyone can see that the answer is accepted (and we both get some rep  ;)

Answer (score 12):

As confirmed in the comments, this is "[The Golden Transcendence](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?24688)" by John C. Wright, the final volume of *The Golden Age* trilogy.

The super soldier of the question is Phaeton; he indeed wears golden armour and pilots a golden ship named the Phoenix Exultant:

> A hundred kilometers from prow to stern, sleek and streamlined as a
> spear blade, a hull of golden adamantium, an artificially stable
> element of unimaginable weight: immeasurably strong, inductile,
> refractory.

The series is indeed set in our solar system, ten thousand years in the future. The sun's power has been harnessed, the planets have been relocated, and all minds are about to merge into a single supermind called the Transcendence. Phaeton combats the "Lords of the Silent Oecumene" who are trying to destroy mankind during this time of vulnerability.